# MySQL get item number on select

Tags: mysql

I am not an expert in MySQL and not sure how to solve this using MySQL only.

I have table like this:

```
mysql> describe items;
   +-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
   | Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
   +-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
   | itemID      | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
   | date        | timestamp           | NO   |     |         |                |               |
   +-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And I would like to get the position of an item as if I will make a selection and sort (or filter). For example, I sort by date and item with itemID=79 will be item with index 126 if I will make a loop. So I would like to get this number 126 directly from database. This is probably similar to ranking but I am not sure but I am not sure if it is possible.

Comment: You want to get item on `index = 126` or know what  index is `itemID=79`

Comment: Index of an itemID=79

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT itemID, date
 FROM (
           SELECT itemID, date, @rn:= @rn +1 as rank 
           FROM items, (SELECT @rn := 0) as para
           ORDER BY date
      ) T
 WHERE rank = 126
```

OR

```
 SELECT itemID, date, rank
 FROM (
           SELECT itemID, date, @rn:= @rn +1 as rank 
           FROM items, (SELECT @rn := 0) as para
           ORDER BY date
      ) T
 WHERE itemID = 79
```

Comment: I have an error " #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: forgot the alias for the parameter

Comment: It works, thanks. Can you please add WHERE statement to the examples? For example where itemID > 500.